# Extrapolate dataset with limited data points and add all values to new dataset

Tags: r, dataset, extrapolation

I have a dataset with very limited data points.

```
 x<- c(4, 8, 13, 24)
 y<- c(40, 37, 28, 20)
 df<- data.frame(x,y)
```

Now I want to extrapolate this data, creating a dataset where the value of y will be given for every value (no decimals) of x between 1-100. x and y have a linear relationship.

Secondly, could this be done for multiple dataframes by using something like a loop?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the relationship between x and y?

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to add this info, it is a linear relationship!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a short snippet that does this:

```r
linear_xy <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
# df <- broom:::augment.lm(linear_xy, newdata = complete(df, x = 1:100)) # one way
df <- df %>%  # another way
  complete(x = 1:100) %>% 
  mutate(.fitted = predict(linear_xy, newdata = .))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggpubr::theme_pubr()
```

This requires that you have the packages `{tidyverse}`, `{broom}`, and `{ggpubr}` installed.

### Second part

Assumming we want to do this with multiple data-frames, we have to
restructure things a bit.

```r
x <- c(4, 8, 13, 24)
y <- c(40, 37, 28, 20)
df <- tibble(x, y)
```

I don't have multiple data-frames (or tibbles), so I'll make this the
primary one, and make up a function (a factory) that yields data-frames, that are a bit different from the above `df`.

```r
df_factory <- . %>% 
  mutate(x_new = x + sample.int(100, size = n()),
         x = if_else(x_new >= 100, x, x_new),
         y_new = y + rnorm(n(), mean = median(y), sd = sd(y)),
         y = y_new,
         y_new = NULL,
         x_new = NULL)
```

Thus `df_factory` is a function of one-variable, and that must be a
data-frame that has an `x` and `y`;

```r
df1 <- df_factory(df)
df2 <- df_factory(df)
df3 <- df_factory(df)
all_dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)
all_dfs <- bind_rows(all_dfs, .id = "df_id")
```

Here we ensure that the relation to the original data-frame is preserved in the `all_dfs` data-frame via the new variable `df_id`.

Next we want to:

- Collapse the variables into their individual data-frame, and we put
  that in a list-column named `data`.
- For each (see `rowwise`) we have to perform:

  - An "interpolating" linear model (not a piece-wise one so...)
  - Predict on each of these `linear_xy` (which are also stored in a list-column`).
- Unnest it all back, so it can be fed into `ggplot` as one contiguous data-frame.

```r
all_dfs %>%
  nest(data = c(x,y)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(linear_xy = list(lm(y ~ x, data = data)),
         augment = list(broom:::augment.lm(linear_xy, 
                                           newdata = complete(data, x = 1:100)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-data, -linear_xy) %>% 
  unnest(augment) -> 
  all_dfs_predictions
```

Note: `->` at the end shows what the pipe result is now assigned to.

The `group` informs `ggplot` to treat the rows as separate via their
`df_id`. And for fun we add the color and fill to also depend on `df_id`. In fact I could have choosen something else to be the `color`aesthetics dependent, like "original `df`" vs. "others" or if a certain threshold should distinguish them, etc.. But then the `group` aesthetic would still tell `ggplot` to separate the rows amongst this relation.

```r
ggplot(all_dfs_predictions, aes(x, y, group = df_id, color = df_id, fill = df_id)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted)) +
  geom_point() +
  lims(x = c(1,100)) +
  ggpubr::theme_pubr()
```

[image: The resulting ggplot2-plot]

Comment: Unfortunately I get this Error: unexpected '=' in "df<- broom:::augment.lm(linear_df, newdata = complete(df, x ="

Comment: Laura, I did present two ways to achieve it. So you'll have to comment the other way out.

Comment: I think something went wrong with the typing, anyway it works now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please mark my answer is the answer then. :)

Comment: If you ask questions on this platform, and you get answers, then you need to mark those answers as valid. Otherwise we, the people providing answers, don't get the credit.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought upvoting did the trick, fairly new here. Just as an additional question. If I have multiple df's,  (df1, df2, df3) with similar content, is there a way to loop your code and make multiple df's with the extrapolated data? THanks!

Comment: If you want, I could ask this in a separate question if that gives you more of the credit

Comment: No that would be unethical. I'll edit the answer, hmm, interesting question though..

Comment: did you see this?

Comment: I just looked at it and it worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Just another additional comment, in the part  """newdata = complete(data, x = 1:100))))""" I want to make the new dataset not give a value per whole number, but per 0.5. Is it possible to specificy this? So in total I would get 200 rows instead of 100.

Comment: Sure! Replace it with `complete(x = seq.default(1, 100, by = 0.5))`.